# Count for how many files can a Unix command be executed

Tags: linux, shell, unix

So I'm given a directory in $dir and an Unix command in $1 I need to check how many files are in $dir directory to which the $1 Unix command can be executed.

```
for dir in `echo $PATH|tr : '\n'`
do
  for file in `find $dir -type f`
  do
    #Here I would like to check if the command works on the file
    then
        echo " $1 $dir/$file works"
    else
        echo " $1 $dir/$file doesn't work"
    fi
  done 
done
```

Comment: Can you define "command can be executed"? Do you mean successfully executed (with return code: 0)? I'm afraid you can't predict it for unknown UNIX command if you don't try to execute it

Comment: yes if it is successfully executed

Comment: If I write this in place of the comment: if `$1 $file` It gives me a lot of errors when I only want to print if it's working or not

Comment: usually UNIX commands if they weren't successful will tell you the file name. IMO the most correct UNIX way to do that would be: `find $dir -type f | xargs $1`

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you want to search through all the files in the `PATH` and, for each file, see if command `$1` succeeds or fails with that file as an argument.  In that case:

```
#!/bin/bash
(IFS=:
find $PATH -type f -exec bash -c 'if "$1" "$2"; then echo "$1 $2 works"; else echo "$1 $2 fails"; fi' None "$1" {} \;
)
```

Or, for greater efficiency:

```
(IFS=:
find $PATH -type f -exec bash -c 'cmd=$1; shift; for f in "$@"; do if "$cmd" "$f"; then echo "$cmd $f works"; else echo "$cmd $f fails"; fi; done' None "$1" {} +
)
```

#### How it works

- `(`

  This starts a subshell.  This is done so that `IFS` returns to its original value after the subshell finishes.
- `IFS=:`

  This tells the shell to do word splitting on `:`.
- `find $PATH -type f -exec bash -c '...' None "$1" {} +`

  This looks for all regular files underneath directories that are in the `PATH` and executes the commands in `'...'` on them.

  More specifically, the commands in `'...'` are given as positional arguments, the name of the command `$1` and one or more (probably many) files to test as arguments.
- The commands in `'...'` are:

  ```
  cmd=$1
  shift
  for f in "$@"; do
      if "$cmd" "$f"
      then echo "$cmd $f works"
      else echo "$cmd $f fails"
      fi
  done
  ```

  These commands test if the command succeeded and report the results.
- `)`

  This closes the subshell

#### Silencing the output from the commands

As glenn jackman suggests, you might not want to see the output from each run of the command `$1` and instead just keep track of whether it succeeded or failed.  In that case, we can redirect the command's output to `/dev/null` as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
(IFS=:;  find $PATH -type f -exec bash -c 'if "$1" "$2" >/dev/null 2>&1; then echo "$1 $2 works"; else echo "$1 $2 fails"; fi' None "$1" {} \; )
```

When this is done, the output may look like:

```
$ bash scriptname ls
ls /bin/keyctl works
ls /bin/mt-gnu works
ls /bin/uncompress works
ls /bin/nano works
ls /bin/zless works
ls /bin/run-parts works
[...snip...]
```

Comment: Love the way you broke down the complicated command into digestable bits. If the OP only cares about the exit status, I would write `if "$cmd" "$f" &>/dev/null`